# Can someone expalin this small python code?

Tags: python

I have already extends the value of `fruits1` to `fruits2` i.e: all the element of `fruits2` should be in the `fruits1` list.
When i tried remove the `"lemon"` with remove method it is showing item is not in the list.

```
fruits1= ["orange" , "apple"]
frutits2=["pineapple" , "lemon"]
fruits1.extends(fruits2)
fruits1.remove(lemon)
print(fruits1)
```

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Typo: change to `fruits1.remove("lemon")`

Comment: `extends` is also a typo

Comment: extends() is not a thing, it is `fruits1.extend(fruits2)`

Comment: `lemon`, without quotations around it, is trying to refer to a variable named `lemon` which doesn't exist in the code you provided. You can write `lemon = "lemon"` before you try to use `list.remove` or you can change `lemon` to `"lemon"` as eyllansec already said

Comment: I'm surprised this even runs, given the `extends` is not a real method of lists and `lemon` is not a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. The method is `extend` not `extends`
2. your variable is called `frutits2` and you are using `fruits2` to extend  the list.
3. You should pass a string to remove an element not a variable (unless that variable is declared somewhere `lemon = 'lemon'`.

Use the following:

```py
fruits1= ["orange" , "apple"]
frutits2=["pineapple" , "lemon"]
fruits1.extend(frutits2)
fruits1.remove('lemon')
print(fruits1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `fruits1.remove("lemon")`.

You attempted to remove an object called ‘lemon’ from your list. It has no such object.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `fruits1.remove(lemon)`. You're trying to remove variable but It's string.Insted try `fruits1.remove('lemon')`.

Answer (score 0):

1- There are a typing mistake in the line 2;
2- Use *extend*, not *extends*;
3- Use *"lemon"*, not *lemon*

```
fruits1= ["orange" , "apple"]
fruits2=["pineapple" , "lemon"]
fruits1.extend(fruits2)
fruits1.remove("lemon")
print(fruits1)
```